# Invoke async method from JS in CefSharp

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, cefsharp

How can I invoke an .NET async method from JS in CefSharp.
I'd like to invoke a method that waits for a console application call.

My idea is the following:
I invoke a method with the signature below:

```
public async Task<int> Calculate(){
```

and when it's finished then its result is given back by a promise on the JS side.
Currently, it doesn't work. When it's finished there is no callback and then I'm not able to invoke it again.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

I came up against the same issue.

An ugly workaround seems to be mangling your method to `async void` and accepting two `IJavascriptCallback` arguments (`resolve` and `reject`).

For example:

```
public class MyCalculator
{
    public async void CalcAsync(
        string name,
        IJavascriptCallback resolve,
        IJavascriptCallback reject)
    {
        try
        {
            if (resolve.IsDisposed)
                return;

            int i = /* compute i */;

            if (!resolve.IsDisposed)
               await resolve.ExecuteAsync(i);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (!reject.IsDisposed)
                await reject.ExecuteAsync(e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Registered as:

```
browser.RegisterAsyncJsObject("myCalculator", new MyCalculator());
```

Then in your JavaScript:

```js
function doThingAsync(name) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        window.myCalculator.calcAsync(name, resolve, reject);
    });
}

var result = await doThingAsync("foo")
```

---

You can pull the pattern out as something like:

```
private static async Task Promisify(IJavascriptCallback resolve, IJavascriptCallback reject, Func<Task> action)
{
    try
    {
        if (!resolve.IsDisposed)
            await action();

        if (!resolve.IsDisposed)
            await resolve.ExecuteAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (!reject.IsDisposed)
            await reject.ExecuteAsync(e.ToString());
    }
}

private static async Task Promisify<T>(IJavascriptCallback resolve, IJavascriptCallback reject, Func<Task<T>> action)
{
    try
    {
        var result = default(T);

        if (!resolve.IsDisposed)
            result = await action();

        if (!resolve.IsDisposed)
            await resolve.ExecuteAsync(result);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (!reject.IsDisposed)
            await reject.ExecuteAsync(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

The bound object's methods would then resemble:

```
public class MyCalculator
{
    public async void CalcAsync(
        string name,
        IJavascriptCallback resolve,
        IJavascriptCallback reject)
    {
        Promisify(resolve, reject, () => /* compute i */);
    }
}
```

---

The (hypothetical) API I'd like to use would resemble:

```
public class MyCalculator
{
    public async Task<int> CalcAsync(string name) => /* compute i */;
}
```

And:

```js
var result = await window.myCalculator.calcAsync("foo")
```

Comment: Support for returning `Task<T>` has been added in https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2758